# How can I make a pytest plugin that adds a fixture configurable?

Tags: pytest

I would like to create a Python package which contains a fixture for pytest. That fixture should mock the behavior of an identification web service. The service contains some parameters for the clients, e.g. a username and a password and other non-credentials. I want the plugin users to set those globally once so that they can test all behavior they want.

I've seen that I can parametrize fixtures and use `pytest.mark.parametrize` to pass the values.

How can I add a global setting for all tests for my fixture?

Comment: See https://github.com/getsentry/responses/issues/597

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement, you have a couple of issues: having a global fixture value shared between tests and having the fixture as a plugin.

First, you can develop your plugin as usual inside your code, along with your tests. A basic version of a shared value can be achieved using a global variable.

Consider this sample code in `conftest.py`:

```
class MyClientClass:
    def __init__(self, auth):
        self.auth = auth


default_client = None


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def web_client(request):
    global default_client
    param = getattr(request, "param", None)
    if param:
        default_client = MyClientClass(request.param)
    return default_client
```

Then your tests can look like this (only the first test does the initialization, the others can benefit the auth):

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize("web_client", [{"user": "user", "pass": "pass"}],
                         indirect=True)
def test_with_init_creds(web_client):
    print(web_client.auth)


def test_some(web_client):
    print(web_client.auth)


def test_another(web_client):
    print(web_client.auth)
```

Now, once you are happy with the local fixture, you can put its code to an installable library. Check out these two links from the official documentation: https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/writing_plugins.html#writing-your-own-plugin and https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/writing_plugins.html#making-your-plugin-installable-by-others. The important thing is to have the entry point `pytest11` so the plugin is discoverable.

I created a very small plugin using poetry, which you can also reference: https://github.com/pksol/pytest-fastapi-deps